# Firebase database data fetched multiple times in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am using ReactJs in my project. I am making a chatting application in I have created 2 components namely **ChatRoom.js** and **InputMessage.js** for the message purpose. **ChatRoom.js** is the chats that are loaded from Firebase Realtime Database and **InputMessage.js** is for handling the message that is shown to the user **InputMessage.js** is working completely fine but the problem is in **ChatRoom.js** I am unable to retrieve the data from the database every time the data is fetched it gets fetched multiple times

This is the code of **ChatRoom.js**

```js
import React, { useState, useEffect, useContext } from 'react';
import Header from './Header';
import { UserNameContext, RoomNameContext } from '../UserContext';
import background from './chatBackground.jpg';
import InputMessage from './InputMessage';
import { database } from '../firebase';

export default function ChatRoom() {
  const { userName, setUserName } = useContext(UserNameContext);
  const { roomName, setRoomName } = useContext(RoomNameContext);
  const messageContainer = {
    backgroundImage: `url(${background})`,
    backgroundRepeat: 'repeat-y !important',
    backgroundAttachment: 'fixed',
    backgroundPosition: 'center center',
    minHeight: '100vh',
    position: 'absolute',
    paddingTop: '100px',
    paddingBottom: '10vh',
    width: '100%'
  };
  const header = {
    position: 'fixed',
    zIndex: 99,
    width: '100%',
    height: 'auto'
  };

  const [details, setDetails] = useState([]);
  const [id, setId] = useState(0);
  useEffect(() => {
    //setDetails([]);
    var path = '';
    path = path.concat('Messages/', roomName, '/');
    var ref = database.ref(path);
    ref.on('value', (data) => {
      var items = data.val();
      var keys = Object.keys(items);
      var messageDB = Object.values(items);
      for (var i = 0; i < keys.length - 1; i++) {
        var k = keys[i];
        console.log(items[k].Message);
      }
    });
  });
  return (
    <div>
      <div style={header}>
        <Header />
      </div>

      <div>
        <div style={messageContainer}>
          {/* details.map(detail =>
          <div className='opponent msg'>{detail}</div>) */}

          {/* <div className='opponent msg'>
            <span className='by'>Deabrnab</span>
            <p>Hey! how are you please let me know how is it going</p>
            <span className='time'>11:20 am</span>
          </div>
          <div className='own msg'>
            <span className='by'>Deabrnab</span>
            <p className='text'>
              euiq gdbhqwdg gdbhqwdg gdbhqwdg gdbhqwdg gdbhqwdg gdbhqwdg
              gdbhqwdgysey
            </p>
            <span className='time'>11:20 am</span>
          </div> */}
        </div>
      </div>

      <InputMessage />
    </div>
  );
}
```

This is the code for **InputMessage.js**

```js
import React, { useState, useEffect, useContext } from 'react';
import send from './sendMessage.png';
import { Input, Container, Row, Col } from 'reactstrap';
import Image from 'react-bootstrap/Image';
import { database } from '../firebase';
import { UserNameContext, RoomNameContext } from '../UserContext';

export default function InputMessage(prop) {
  var moment = require('moment');
  const { userName, setUserName } = useContext(UserNameContext);
  const { roomName, setRoomName } = useContext(RoomNameContext);

  const design = {
    width: '100%',
    background: 'black'
  };

  const [message, setMessage] = useState('');
  const date = moment().format('YYYYMMDD');
  const time = moment().format('h:mm a');
  const messageToDB = () => {
    const data = {
      Sender: userName,
      Message: message,
      Date: date,
      Time: time
    };
    var path = '';
    path = path.concat('Messages', '/', roomName);
    var ref = database.ref(path);
    ref.push(data);

    setMessage('');
  };
  return (
    <div style={design}>
      <Container>
        <Row>
          <div className='msg-textbox'>
            <Col>
              <Input
                className='input'
                type='text'
                placeholder='Type Message...'
                value={message}
                onChange={(e) => setMessage(e.target.value)}
              />
            </Col>
          </div>
          <div>
            <Col>
              <Image
                src={send}
                onClick={() => messageToDB()}
                className='send'
              />
            </Col>
          </div>
        </Row>
        <div></div>
      </Container>
    </div>
  );
}
```

This is the part where I am reading data from database in **ChatRoom.js** and whenever I am storing a message in the array it is getting stored in the array as previous data + the current fetched data

```js
var path = '';
path = path.concat('Messages/', roomName, '/');
var ref = database.ref(path);
ref.on('value', (data) => {
  setDetails([]);
  var items = data.val();
  var keys = Object.keys(items);
  var messageDB = Object.values(items);
  for (var i = 0; i < keys.length - 1; i++) {
    var k = keys[i];
    //console.log(items[k].Message);
    details.push(items[k].Message);
  }
  console.log(details);
});
```

[image: Like this]

my data format in the database is
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Solved using set instead of array and timestamp as key